# JSON String too Large for StringEntity

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, string-length, android-memory

In my app I turn an image into a bas64 string and add it to a JSON object to send to the server. The problem seems to be that the string is too large? Originally I was getting an out of Memory error now the response just returns null and Ive debugged it to the point where I have found it to be that the String I pass to my StringEntity Object is too large. I have read alot of other answers but none have worked or they just don't quite apply to what I need to do. The Code is as follows

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(JSONArray... params) {

        JSONObject allPostObj = new JSONObject();
        try {

            allPostObj.put("receiptImgs", params[0]);

            //Log.e("in obj Try" , allPostObj.toString());

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            // WCF service path
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/path");
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
            // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
            int timeoutConnection = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            httpPost.setParams(httpParameters);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(allPostObj.toString());
            Log.e("DEBUGGING",allPostObj.toString());
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");                 
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);         
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpEntity.getContent()));
            String readLine = reader.readLine();
            Log.d("DEBUG RESPONSE",readLine);
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(readLine);

            answer = jsonResponse.getString("saveImageResult");
            Log.e("returning", answer);
        }
```

And replacing the line

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(allPostObj.toString());
```

With:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{\"receiptImgs\":[{\"imgString\":\"\",\"imgPath\":\"test\"}]}");
```

Works just fine

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should not use StringEntity for large content, you should switch to `FileEntity` or `InputStreamEntity`, depending on where you store your data.

---

quick fix you may try (not compiled/tested):

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(allPostObj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(stream , -1);
```

Comment: And any idea how this would change my back end? Is there something I would need to change there as well

Comment: Why dont you use FileEntity? Images might be very large, while converting image to json you should do it in a streaming way and store results in file, dont load all data to memory, otherwise OOM error will show up from time to time, in most unexpected moments.

Comment: I will definitely look into this. Any suggestions for a quick fix until I can fully implement FileEntity correctly?

Comment: added quick fix to answer

Comment: Tried that but the same issue occurs

Comment: Upon reviewing it further I found the real error which I still do not know how to fix but I came up with a work around check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023693/bitmap-changes-size-gets-almost-20-times-larger?noredirect=1#comment31602184_21023693 if youre interested in the real issue