# Bitmap changes size. Gets almost 20 times larger

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

In my android app the user takes and saves a picture it is then converted to a bas64 string where it is about 55000 characters long. Then later in the program I retrieve the image and again convert it to a base64 string except now its over 2 million characters. Can any one explain why this happens?

code for re-retrieving the image.

```
Bitmap imgBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imgFilePath));
```

Comment: This will not answer your question but is there any specific reason for converting it to `String` ?

Comment: Im sending it to a server. I understand this isnt the best way to do it and Im currently changing the implementation but I still would like to know whats happening

Comment: No, it's not. One of the problems might be encoding, for example you don't use the same amount of space for storing an UTF-8 (2 or 3 bytes), an UTF-16 (2 bytes) and UTF-32(4 bytes).

Comment: Well even if the encoding did change that max diff is what twice as many bytes UTF-8/16 to UTF-32 thats a long way from 20.

Comment: Maybe (just an idea)... you use a **jpg** for encoding and then save a **png** while decoding.